# For distinct primes $p$ and $q$, does any group of order $p^2q$ have a subgroup of order $p$ (without using Sylow or Cauchy)?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, alternative-proof

### The Details:

I'm reading *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition),"* by Gallian.

This is based on Exercise 7.40 of the "Cosets and Lagrange's Theorem" section *ibid.* Here it is for convenience:

> Prove that a group of order $63$ must have an element of order $3$.

*What I've noticed about the motivating question:*

We have $63=3^2\times 7$ and we're looking for an element (and therefore a subgroup) of order $3$.

Everything I could find online or think of uses Sylow's Theorems. That would be an anachronism since they're not covered in the book so far, so, therefore, I suppose, there ought to be a proof *sans* this result. The same is true of Cauchy's Theorem.

But I'm thinking bigger . . . Hence:

### The Question:

> For distinct primes $p$ and $q$, does any group $G$ of order $p^2q$ have a subgroup of order $p$?$^\dagger$ Moreover, can this be proven without using Sylow's Theorems or Cauchy's Theorem?

### Thoughts:

If $G$ is cyclic, then for any nontrivial $g\in G$, we have

\begin{align}
e&=g^{|G|} \\
&= g^{p^2q} \\
&= (g^{pq})^p,
\end{align}

so $g^{pq}$ has order (at most?) $p$ (but $p$ is prime so . . . ). Thus we are done.

I'm not sure what to do next. I have a vague idea of applying Cayley's Theorem followed by the Orbit-Stabiliser Theorem, although the former wouldn't tell us much about the orbit of an element.

Please help :)

---

$\dagger$ Yes, by Sylow's Theorems, right? But wait . . .

Comment: If you don't want to use Sylow, can we use [Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory))?

Comment: No, @Arthur; it's not covered yet. Thank you though :)

Comment: If not then all nontrivial elements have order $7$, but $6$ does not divide $62$, so that is impossible.

Comment: That's very succinct, @DerekHolt. Thank you! :)